# MySQL: counting two fields

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Pizza  ----|| Topping 
====================
Cheese--||    Olives
====================
Ham-----     || Tuna
====================
Cheese-- || Olives
====================
Cheese-- || Tuna
====================
```

I would like to obtain the number of pizzas of each type, so in the table above  there would be one ham pizza, and 2 cheese pizzas (since cheese+olives is repeated and should be counted only once). Basically, I need to count each row for each two equal elements and group by pizza.

The result from that query should be:

```
Pizza  ----|| Count
====================
Cheese--||    2
====================
Ham-----     || 1
====================
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Pizza, count( distinct Topping) as cnt
from your_pizza_table
group by Pizza
order by cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT pizza, count(distinct pizza,topping) FROM test GROUP BY pizza;
```